# How to make a navbar fixed in html and css?

Tags: html, css

I am designing a website and i would like to have the navbar fixed on my page so that you dont have to scroll all the way back up to navigate the website. I know how to do this using for example `position: fixed;` etc however cannot find a working solution

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">
<link rel='shorcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='circle.ico' />
</head>
<body>

<title>Home</title>

<div class="header">
  <h3 class="logo" id='logo'>Name</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
  <label for="chk" class="show-menu-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
  </label>

  <ul class="menu" id='navbar'>
    <a href="#section1">Home</a>
    <a href="#section2">About</a>
    <a href="#">Calendar</a>
    <a href="#">News</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <label for="chk" class="hide-menu-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </label>
  </ul>
</div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
body {
  background-image: url('img5.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "montserrat",sans-serif;
}
.header{
  height: 100px;
  background: #34495e;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
.logo{
  line-height: 100px;
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu{
  float: right;
  line-height: 100px;
}
.menu a{
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.show-menu-btn,.hide-menu-btn{
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
.show-menu-btn{
  float: right;
}
.show-menu-btn i{
  line-height: 100px;
}
.menu a:hover,
.show-menu-btn:hover,
.hide-menu-btn:hover{
  color: #3498db;
}

#chk{
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -1111;
}

.content{
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.content img{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.content p{
  text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .show-menu-btn,.hide-menu-btn{
    display: block;
  }
  .menu{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #333;
    right: -100%;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 80px 0;
    line-height: normal;
    transition: 0.7s;
  }
  .menu a{
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .hide-menu-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 40px;
  }
  #chk:checked ~ .menu{
    right: 0;
  }
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
p {
  font-size: 120%;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 130%;
}
```

Things i have tried:

```
.menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thankyou!!! :D

Comment: _“I am unsure on how to do this”_ - then you should _start_ with some research.

Comment: I have been doing research however solutions that I have found do not work which is why I have come to stack overflow....

Comment: Show us what you tried then, and explain what the specific problem was. There is little point in people suggesting the usual approaches here now, if you tried those already, but they won’t work for some reason with your specific layout setup.

Comment: ok done i have added solutions that I have tried

Comment: there 3 (4) ways to do it: `postion: fixed;`, `position: sticky;` and `position: absolute`. Also if you do a 100vh css-grid templating or flexbox templating you can do it as well but thats a way more difficault approach.

Comment: ok i have tried all three however ```position: sticky;``` doesnt to do anything to the nav bar unlike the ohers which move the attribute tags to the left. However the attribute tags are then fixed excpet the logo and the background color. Am i missing some parameters for ```position: sticky;``` , becasue on its own it doesnt do anything

Comment: I don’t see what sense positioning the menu on its own should have here to begin with, I think you should apply `position:fixed` to the `.header`, if anything. And `sticky` has specific requirements regarding what environment it needs to be put in - stuff one can go _read up_ on, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: @CBroe as you see in his codes that tried to apply position-fixed to the `.menu` (navbar). Means he only wants to apply this to the navbar not the entire header. `position: sticky;` wont work within the header because it will be pulled out of the screen as a child. So it needs to be exculded and a standalone to allow to stick to the top of the screen without getting dragged outside of the screen.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i am trying to acheive

Comment: So what you already tried would have worked fine already then, if you just left out `left:0` …

Comment: Thanks CBroe!!! I have just added that with some tweaks to the header and the menu. Then i added ```margin-top: 100px; ``` to the ```.content```. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the header position:fixed and width 100%. After that give a top margin to the page content, so that the header don't overlap the Content.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">
<link rel='shorcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='circle.ico' />
</head>
<body>

<title>Home</title>

<div class="header">
  <h3 class="logo" id='logo'>Name</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
  <label for="chk" class="show-menu-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
  </label>

  <ul class="menu" id='navbar'>
    <a href="#section1">Home</a>
    <a href="#section2">About</a>
    <a href="#">Calendar</a>
    <a href="#">News</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <label for="chk" class="hide-menu-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </label>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
.header{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #34495e;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
.content{
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

I hope this is helpfull.

Comment: perfect :D I have incoporated ```margin-top: 100px;``` with some of the suggestions from the comments and have got it working. Thankyou :D

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a z-index. Also disabling scroll ability keeps your header at top but only because the website cant scroll at all.

The main issue you have, is that the navbar is insdie the header and cant leave the header container.

So exclude the navbar from the ehader and use sticky on it with top 0;

```css
.menu {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<title>Home</title>

<div class="header">
  <h3 class="logo" id='logo'>Name</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
  <label for="chk" class="show-menu-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
  </label>
</div>

<ul class="menu" id='navbar'>
  <a href="#section1">Home</a>
  <a href="#section2">About</a>
  <a href="#">Calendar</a>
  <a href="#">News</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <label for="chk" class="hide-menu-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </label>
</ul>

<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```